# error in start another Activity

Tags: android-activity

i built a program that  its main page contains two buttons now.second button doesn't work.but first button starts activity.
the second one is "btninfo".
(InfoActivity is defined in manifest.xml)
i have written the codes of MainActivity below:

```
package com.hesamapps.build;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmain);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AmazingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btninfo);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,InfoActivity.class);
                  startActivity(a);
            }
            });
}
```

---

and the InfoActivity below:

```
package com.hesamapps.build;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

public class InfoActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.onStart();
        setContentView(R.layout.info);
    }
}
```

---

button must start InfoActivity but it makes force close error.
(Button  is "btninfo")

Comment: Can you post your LogCat output?

Comment: Thanks.problem is solved. I think compiling or building apk were wrong.I use AIDE (Android IDE) for application development.